# What do I need to do to correct 'Cannot create ActiveX component.' when creating Active Directory object?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I am working on some older code that is now throwing an error after we upgraded to Windows 10. The error message is

> Cannot create ActiveX component.

I have traced it to the following line of code:

```
Dim sys_info As Object

'*** Get the User's distinguished name and LDAP path (person running the program)

sys_info = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
```

I am not sure what may have changed to cause this to start throwing the error message. The compiled program still works as expected, but with it throwing this error message, it can be a bit off putting to use.

Comment: Are you really using VBA, or is this vbscript?  You mention Visual Studio, so it doesn't seem like this would be VBA...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with visual basic, so you are probably right. The file extension is `.vb` Please let know if that is the case, so I can update the tag for this question.

Comment: A `.vb` file is a Visual Basic file - `.vbs` would be VBScript.  Exactly how are you executing this code?

Comment: Okay. I believe I found the correct tag, as the application as a whole is a vb project that creates a simple executable with a gui. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction tag wise.

Comment: Windows 10 disables ActiveX by default, and re-enabling is... it's not easy, and it's not smart; it was turned of for a reason. You may have to re-write this whole thing to use `System.DirectoryServices`.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX seems like overkill, even for an old script.

You can actually bind directly to an AD object by LDAP using the SID (without having to search for it), and you can easily get the SID of the current using from [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent).

My VB is rusty, so there might be errors in this, but this should bind to the AD object of the current user, and retrieve the `distinguishedName` attribute:

```
Dim user = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" & WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value & ">")
user.RefreshCache(New String() { "distinguishedName" })

Dim dn = user.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString()
```

Comment: This script isn't to get the information of the current user. It's used for the helpdesk to unlock user's accounts. Helpdesk searches by a user's username and if they are locked, gives them the option to unlock them.

Comment: Ah ok. I was just going by the comment in your code: `(person running the program)`. There are some examples [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19689/Working-with-Active-Directory-in-VB-NET) you can use, especially the example that uses [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) to find an account.